# Se puede actualizar un modelo en Laravel sin tener que volver a correr las migraciones?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Dentro de la función providerproducts se realiza la inserción de datos sin ningún problema, pero al añadir 3 ultimos campos (precioPublicoUnitario, precioPublicoSubtotal, precioPublicoTotal) estos no se guardan,las referencias estan bien, hay algún modo de actualizar sin volver a correr las migraciones?

```
public function providerproducts()

    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ProviderProduct::class, 
       'comparative_table_products','id_cuadro', 'id_productosproveedores')->withPivot('created_at', 
        'updated_at', 'precioUSD', 'precioMXN','subtotal', 'iva','total', 'precioPublicoUnitario', 
        'precioPublicoSubtotal', 'precioPublicoTotal');
    }
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código como **texto** y no como imagen.

Answer (score 1):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta:

Si puedes agregar nuevos campos a la tabla sin correr la migracion haciendolo desde **PhPMyAdmin** en caso de usar **MySQL**, el problema de este procedimiento es que al portar la aplicacion a otro servidor no vas a tener los nuevos campos agregados porque no estaran en la construccion de la migracion, claro a menos que importes las tablas completamente, pero igualmente ya la bitacora de migrate perdio integridad en su contenido.

**Otra solucion que te recomiendo** es crear una migracion para  agregarle los nuevos campos y asi mantener la estructura tambien en Laravel.

**Ejemplo de esto seria asi:**

Codigo inicial de la creacion de la **tabla usuarios**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('usuarios', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Voy agregar dos campos mas a la tabla usuario con el comando artisan:

```
php artisan make:migration usuarios_EditTable --table=usuarios
```

El codigo de la migracion para agregar las nuevas columnas es el siguiente:

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('usuarios', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('apellido');
            $table->string('pais');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        // pregunta si existe la columna antes de borrarla
        if (Schema::hasColumn('users', 'name'))
        {
            Schema::table('usuarios', function (Blueprint $table) {
                //
                $table->dropColumn(['apellido', 'pais', ]);
            });
        }
    }
```

Al ejecutar la migracion para actualizar las nuevas columnas el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con este ejemplo trato de explicarte que la migracion son favorables, no me han borrado el contenido anterior de la tabla y llevo la bitacora de los cambios de la tabla desde Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede crear una nueva migracion para agregar los campos que te faltan el la tabla.

en [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#creating-columns) explican como.

Por ejemplo. crea una migración con lo siguiente

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('email');
});
```

Acuerdate de hacer un dropColumn en la parte de `public function down()` para poder hacer un rollback y deshacer la ultima migración

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->dropColumn('email');
});
```

Ahora si haces `php artisan migrate` solo aplicara las nuevas migraciones.

`php artisan migrate:fresh` borrara todo y vuelve a crear las tablas

`php artisan migrate:refresh` hace todo los rollback (el function down de cada migración) y vuelve a ejecutar las migraciones

`php artisan rollback` deshace la ultima migracion

Si te sale un error que el campo no puede ser nulo tienes que poner

```
# Si quieres que sea NULL
$table->string('email')->nullable()
# Para poner un valor por defecto
$table->string('email')->default('example@email.com')
```